# Bootstrap navbar active css class - How to apply to sub-content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

My Bootstrap navbar has 3 main menu links and no sub-menus.  The 3 links are essentially categories. If you click on a menu link its text color is changed to reflect the page you are on with this CSS:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
color: #e6321e;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make all content for a specific category to be able to control the active state of its category menu link so the menu text remains colored when viewing sub-content.  This will make specific sub-content appear to be associated with a particular category.

The Bootstrap navbar is on every page so the navbar-nav class is available to manipulate. I don't want to use sub-menus.

I tried creating a block and using the Block Class module to apply the navbar-nav class to it, but have not been able to get it to work obviously.

Another thought is maybe using wildcards in menu links?

Thanks for your time and thoughts.